# GWT how to change textbox without running change handler

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT. I have a textbox and a drop down list box that have change handlers on them.  I also sometimes change the text or selected value from the source code but I don't want the change handler to run when I do this, I only want it to run when the user changes it.

How can I implement this?

Comment: The onBlur could be a good option, but when you select a value from the list box it doesn't run (lose focus) until you click away from the list box.

Answer (score 3):

For the `TextBox`, use [`setValue(T value, boolean fireEvents)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html#setValue%28T,%20boolean%29) using `false` as second argument, to avoid firing any `ValueChangeEvent`.

For the `ListBox`, when you call [`setSelectedIndex(int index)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29) or [`setItemSelected(int index, boolean selected)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html#setItemSelected%28int,%20boolean%29) the `ChangeEvent` is *never* fired, so you are free to use them programmatically and rely on the `ChangeHandler` on user action.

Comment: What about drop down boxes and using setSelectedIndex.  That does not appear to have a boolean fireEvent option.

Comment: Sorry forgot the listbox part: you do not need to to anything in such case. Updated answer.